# How to display controls which are not bound to SObject field?

Tags: apex, visualforce

My assumption is that `<apex:inputfield>` always requires SObject Field.

In the scenario where I am showing a list of SObject records {Record 1, Record 2,...Record N}  using StandardSetController then how can I display a UI control (Eg: DatePicker) without it being bound to an underlying SObject field ?

I am assuming that I cannot use dummy fields in this scenario because it is a standardsetcontroller and always retrieves/displays a list of records.

Hope I am clear.

If not plz let know I will elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could add an extension to display the dummy record of any sObject of your choosing that has a date field.
2. You can use a library like jQuery UI or Bootstrap or similar to display a datepicker

Comment: For "1". Can you plz expand ?. I assume that you mean for me to retrieve any SObject date field from any SObject record ?.       For "2" I am unfamiliar with jQuery so I assuming from what you have said that it would be possible to display a DatePicker control using jQuery and bind it to a controller property instead of a SObject field ..am I right ?

Comment: Yes and Yes....